# Pronunciation of antifa?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm hearing all kinds of pronunciations for *antifa* :

- ən'ti:fə
- æn'ti:fə
- 'æntɪfɑ:
- æntɪ'fɑ:

The word has recently become more prominent.  Do fascists and antifascists say it in the same way?  Any difference between American and English pronunciation?

Comment: Hi, petitrien. The first result for "antifa pronunciation" on Google produces a link to a [Merriam-Webster article](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/words-were-watching-antifa) concerning the origin of the word, along with a [Cambridge Dictionary page](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/antifa) that includes the British and American English pronunciation of the word. Should you have any other concerns, please make an edit to reflect them. Otherwise, this question will most likely be closed.

Comment: Thank you!  I note that the Cambridge Dictionary doesn't record the pronunciations that I hear most, namely the ones stressed on the second syllable.

Comment: https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=34177